# Quit program when 2d array doesn't have the specific element left

Tags: java

I'd like to make my program quit when the 2d array doesn't have any "X" left in it. I'm replacing them with "1" with user input (x and y). How should I do it? And also, if you see something wrong in my code, I'd would highly appreciate it if you could point that out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MultiArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MultiArrays mu = new MultiArrays();
        String firstArray[][] = { { "X", "X", "X" }, { "X", "X", "X" } };
        boolean quit = true;

        do {
            mu.display(firstArray);
            mu.pickNum(firstArray);
            mu.display(firstArray);
            System.out.println();
        } while (quit == true);
    }

    public void display(String x[][]) {
        for (int row = 0; row < x.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < x[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(x[row][col] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void pickNum(String x[][]) {

        System.out.println("Pick row number (0-1) >");
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Pick column number (0-2) >");
        int num2 = scan.nextInt();
        x[num][num2] = "1";

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With your `quit` variable set to `true` you could do something like this:

```
boolean quit=true;
do {   // no matter what value quit has, we would loop at least once
     mu.display(firstArray);
     mu.pickNum(firstArray);
     mu.display(firstArray);
     System.out.println();

     for (int row = 0; row < firstArray.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < firstArray[row].length; col++) {
            quit &= !firstArray[row][col].equalsIgnoreCase("X");   // do boolean AND while checking each element if it is something else than "X"
        }
     }
  } while (!quit);  // stop looping when quit is set to true
```

The line

```
quit &= !firstArray[row][col].equalsIgnoreCase("X");
quit = quit & !firstArray[row][col].equalsIgnoreCase("X")  // the same but longer
```

does evaluate to `true` if and only if *all* elements of your arrays are **not** `"X"`

Comment: This is by far inferior to my solution. The OP had the good sense to have at least some of the logic decomposed to multiple methods, and you dump code that could stand nicely in its own method in this one, adding a new responsibility to the already bloated `main`. This also means keeping the pointless `quit` variable, when it could be nicely eliminated. The `equalsIgnoreCase` is utterly pointless and introduces an unnecessary inefficiency.

Comment: @janos: sorry that you don't like my solution. Yes you are right, encapsulating functionality into separate methods is in most cases better (especially concerning maintainability of the program). But I don't think that introducing a method, which is only executed once makes it a superior solution. Additionally, no one ever said that deciding whether to quit the program or not should be part of the `MultiArrays` class. Only because in this one case OP decides to quit the program based on the arrays, does not mean that this logic will or can be reused in another part of the program.